# Why aren't there Tokina lens profiles in Lightroom, and how do I get one for mine?

Tags: lens, lightroom, software, tokina

I have a Nikon D90 and a Tokina 11-16mm.

I want a lens profile for Adobe Lightroom, and it seems they have all known brands out of the box *but* Tokina.

1. Why is that?
2. How can I add a profile for my lens?

Comment: Honestly, #1 does not matter and you probably wont find an answer. #2 is a good question though.

Answer (score 7):

No one seems to supply those and would be prohibitively expensive to create general ones because you would need a lot of copies of the lens to account for variations and quality control issues.

However, you can create one that will work for your own lens and camera combination using the [Adobe Lens Profile Creator](http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/lensprofile_creator/).

Comment: yes but Tokina was available in Lightroom 4. Is this a bug maybe? Can I transfer from 4?

Answer (score 6):

I downloaded a profile for that lens using the [Adobe Lens Profile Downloader](http://blogs.adobe.com/labs/archives/2010/10/the-lens-profile-downloader-now-available.html). As far as I know, these are community-submitted profiles, so there may be quality issues. The profile I got is fine, though.

Answer (score 1):

If you are desperate, you can try using something developed by lightroom users. Boyan Silyavski has shared one, has great reviews from other users and also its widely used. You can get it [HERE](http://www.1000and1.info/2010/08/camara-raw-tokina-11-16mm-28-canon-lens.html).
PS: This is for Canon mount 11-16mm, you might need to tweak it a little before using it.